# Page aligned to center IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On this site I'm gonna offer this Xmas to my brothers-in-law, I have a page structure like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="menu">[...]</div>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="section1">[...]</div>
            <div id="section2">[...]</div>
            etc etc etc
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

All looks perfect on Firefox... but on my IE9, the page isn't aligned and the @font-face isn't loading either...

The CSS goes like this (looks to me there's no problem here)

```
#container{width:960px;margin:0 auto;position:relative}
#wrapper{width:780px;float:right;margin-bottom:30px}
#menu{width:180px;float:left;background:url(../img/site/menu_bg.jpg) repeat-y right;height:100%;position:fixed;padding-top:55px}
```

Already tried a different set-ups with no change at all ... and I'm starting to rip my hair off here ... any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

PS: If it helps ... the page in question is: www.sweetdreams.pt/escondido.php

**EDIT:** As requested ... this is the beggining of the code in the page:

```
<?php if(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler")) ob_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-PT">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you by any chance running IE in Compatibility Mode? (check this by pressing F12 and looking at the Developer tools below in the browser window.

EDIT:

In IE, it pays to have a DOCTYPE declaration, otherwise it will just go to Quirks mode.

Please do post full HTML source.

Comment: Edited my question with the begining of the php file I have. By pressing F12 I noticed I had IE in Quirks mode ... when changed to IE9 rules, the page got aligned as intended. Now... How can I fix this deal with entering quirks mode?

Comment: if you have the DOCTYPE, IE should go automatically to IE9 mode. Otherwise, it should be an issue with the developer tools. Let me check and i'll get back 2 you.

Comment: Nope, sorry to say I haven't found anything that could help you further.

Comment: Should my response help you with your issue, please don't forget to mark it as answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Yes it did help ... seems the problem was on my end. Still didn't quite get to grasp the why IE entered Quirks mode as the doctype declaration I had is perfectly valid. Anyway ... thanks... you tought me a new thing !

Comment: Glad I could be of service.

Answer (score 2):

The document type declaration must be at the very first line in the file, otherways it's ignored. It also must not preceeded by any characters, i.e. no blank lines, spaces, tabs, nothing, just `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Problem was I had the <?php if(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler")) ob_start(); ?> there :) it's fixed now! thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

instead of { margin: 0 auto; } try...

```
#container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: -480px; /* half of width */
}
```